# How to resolve error Conversion to Dalvik format failed?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [“Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1” on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

when i m running my application this will show this error in console.

> Unable to execute dex: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
>
> Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: invalid LOC header (bad
> signature)

can any one help me out what is this error? why this error occurs.

Comment: Check the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar

Comment: @Richard Lee I have already try this but it doesn't work.

Comment: i think there are two android library in your java build path..check it..

Comment: can you post a picture if your librarie and your "order and export"?

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a problem with your libraries.

Go to Eclipse, then right click your project, go to properties, android build path, then libraries. In your list of libraries delete everything EXCEPT your android X.X.X file

You can also try to do project --> clean