# Millennial Media interstitial crash

Tags: android

In the onCreate() method of the activity I want the interstitial to appear in, 
I have the following code:

```
MMAdView interAdView = new MMAdView(this, MY_APP_ID, MMAdView.FULLSCREEN_AD_LAUNCH, true, null);
interAdView.fetch();
interAdView.setListener(new BasicMMAdListener()
{
 @Override
 public void MMAdCachingCompleted(MMAdView adview, boolean success)
 {
   if(success)
     adview.display();
 }
});
```

The code compiles without error, but at runtime I get the following Log output
which indicates an error at the first line of my code snippet, i.e. the one 
starting: `MMAdView interAdView = new MMAdView(this, ...`

```
Could not find class 'com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView', referenced from method com.mycompany.mygame.myactivity.onCreate
```

I am puzzled because I thought that if there was somehow a missing 
class then the app should not compile.

Comment: Hope you have cleaned your project and recompiled...

Comment: @Vinay: Yes... but I keep getting "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" which I then fix buy removing jars and adding them again... yuk!

Comment: maybe I should first resolve my "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" issue first.

Comment: Can you open the jar using some zip tools to look for the MMAdView calss present or not? May be that might give you some insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Vinay's comment, it forced me to investigate another problem I'd been having first.

My problem disappeared when I resolve an earlier problem covered on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar).