# import jar in eclipse and then has the error

Tags: android

I import jar in eclipse, and it always prompt the error: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1.

[image]

What is the problem?

Any idea?

Comment: you mean error while exporting the app then?

Comment: I think in your jar file some classfiles are conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [this steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar) and read [this page](http://bimbim.in/post/2010/09/24/Reason-of-Conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1.aspx). In short, clean your project and remove all your external jars. If your error dissapears than add your jar again, if not something else is wrong. You get [a lot of hits](https://www.google.nl/search?q=Conversion+to+Dalvik+format+failed+with+error+1&oq=Conversion+to+Dalvik+format+failed+with+error+1&aqs=chrome.0.57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=nl&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=conversion+to+dalvik+format+failed+with+error+1+external+jar&oq=Conversion+to+Dalvik+format+failed+with+error+1+ex&gs_l=serp.1.1.0j0i30l2j0i5i30.1580.2055.0.2885.3.3.0.0.0.0.55.142.3.3.0...0.0...1c.1.76uEicG_es4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355272958,d.d2k&fp=720dc4405ea98172&bpcl=39942515&biw=1360&bih=643) when you use Google to find your problem