# Amazon S3 ends up with Error "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-upload

I know this is a well known issue of **"Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"**.

I goggled for it also but it is not able to solve my problem.

My Goal is to **integrate Amazon s3 to upload image** from my Android application.

I just download **aws-android-sdk-1.4.4** from [here](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid) and following reference links like,

[Mobile Photo Uploads to Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3002109349624271)

[Getting Started Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/gsg/Welcome.html)

I started with Creating New **Android Project ver 4.1.2** and copied all `jar files` available with aws-**android-sdk-1.4.4** to `libs` folder of my application.

**Problem Start here only,**

I am trying to run my application and it is throwing this error **"Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"**.

**Note :** I have just copied `jar files` to `libs` folder only and not `imported` yet into application.

**I have two questions regarding this.**

1. How to solve this **"Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"** error?
2. My only need is to **upload image to Amazon S3 server**, Is all **jar files** are required to add?

**EDIT :**

Following are the jar files I got with **aws-android-sdk-1.4.4**.

1. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4.jar
2. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-autoscaling.jar
3. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-cloudwatch.jar
4. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-core.jar
5. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-ddb.jar
6. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-ddb-mapper.jar
7. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-ddb-mapper-debug.jar
8. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-debug.jar
9. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-ec2.jar
10. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-elb.jar
11. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-s3.jar
12. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-sdb.jar
13. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-ses.jar
14. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-sns.jar
15. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-sqs.jar
16. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-sts.jar

Any help is Appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I find that this error generally occurred for me when the same jar file has been duplicated in multiple places. Check for these conditions

Comment: @Slartibartfast thanks for the reply. I have edited my question with list of jar files available and being used.

Comment: Basically you have to check for  two or more JAR files on your buildpath that include the same package and classes - this will cause this error

Comment: Also clean the project - look here for more on this error
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar

Comment: @Slartibartfast not getting exactly. Can you explain me a bit more. And I have clean up and restart eclipse many times also.

Comment: Have you tried the S3_Uploader example included in the SDK?  Do you get the same error there as well?  That might point to a problem with your eclipse setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I help maintain the AWS SDK for Android and I'm sorry you're encountering problems.  Regarding the second part of your question first,  As noted in the [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/gsg/Welcome.html):

> Copy either a bundled JAR for all services or the specific JARs for the services you wish to use. You have 3 options:
>
> Add **aws-android-sdk-VERSION-debug.jar**. This JAR creates the largest APK, but allows for full stack traces during development.
>
> Add **aws-android-sdk-VERSION.jar**. This JAR creates a smaller APK and a simple bundle when releasing your application.
>
> Add the **aws-android-sdk-VERSION-core.jar** plus the JARs for the individual services your project will use. This method creates the smallest APK, but requires a more complicated setup.
>
> Note, copying both bundled JARs and service JARs will cause errors.

In your cases this translates to using one of the 3 following setups:

1. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4.jar
2. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-debug.jar
3. aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-core.jar **and** aws-android-sdk-1.4.4-s3.jar

Regarding your error, as noted in other comments: make sure you have not included multiple copies of JAR files in your build path and also make sure you have not copied more than the necessary AWS SDK JARs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes that solve my problem and now I am able to run my application. Now getting this error `com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection to https://s3.amazonaws.com refused` while creating `s3 client` object. Will check that at my end. Thanks again.