# How to detect package name conflicts

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm getting the dreadful "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1". I've seen the thread  ["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar).

My question is how to detect if there are package name conflicts in my project. It's a large project so doing it manually may not be possible or will take too much time.

Also, is there a way to figure out if a jar in included more than once in a project?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how to detect if there are package name conflicts in my project.

At the risk of appearing to give a fatuous answer, the simplest way is to attempt to convert to Dalvik format.  That will tell you if there is a conflict.  Fix it ... then repeat the process.  (And the problem is multiple classes with the same fully qualified name ... not package name conflicts.)

> Also, is there a way to figure out if a jar in included more than once in a project.

I'd have thought that visual inspection of the build path should be sufficient.

---

I'm not aware of any special tools for doing these things, but I'm not convinced that you need special tools.  Not even for a complicated project.