# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 in Android

Tags: android, dalvik

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1” on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

I'm getting this error :  Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
It started to gave me this error after loading facebook SDK. What is the problem?

I searched a lot on the internet but I couldn't solve my problem. What can I do?
Here is my console :

```
[2013-01-17 15:03:14 - Mert] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter$1;
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:180)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:703)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1000)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[2013-01-17 15:03:14 - Mert] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2013-01-17 15:03:14 - Mert] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Here is my Build Path :

[image: a busy cat]

Thanks for your help.

Regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3389640/646806

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ or Eclipse to compile your project?

Comment: Solutions to errors conversion of dalvik failure format and error sun / misc / basecoder64 in Eclipse.
Instructions to solve the problem are:
    Install Windows XP sp2 with Java 6 or Ubuntu.
    Download adt version 23.0.2 with SDK 19.
    Decompress the adt and install it on your computer.
    Open the Eclipse as administrator and import the android file.
    In the file project.properties write this -> target = android-19 <-- very important.
    Export your project and this error will no more appear.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove all the referenced library file from your project and clean the project...this will remove the error..

**OR**

try to delete all the jar file from your java build path and then again attach from lib folder..

Comment: Exactly, which ones of them i must delete? If I delete one of them can be there any problem in project?

Comment: universal image loader.jar

Comment: Sure?
I deleted universal image loader and tried to run, again it didn't worked
I added facebookSDK and I have a Session.java file and facebook SDK has Session.java file too. Is thıs cause the problem?

Comment: So, first try to rename your Session.java file to other name and try again..if not succeed then try my answer

Comment: I tried your answer and now I'm trying to change Session.java

Comment: but don't change facebook sdk's Session.java file

Comment: I removed universal image loader.jar and I'm still getting same error.

Comment: Cleaning worked for me.

Comment: YOU SOLUTION FOR YOU. 1- YOU CAN ALSO REMOVE THE LIBRARY THAT YOU DO NOT USE 2- AFTER CLEAN THE PROJECT. 3- RETURN TO COPY THE PROJECT AUTOMATICALLY. 4- COPILAS THE PROJECT IN JAR AND READY

Comment: Solutions to errors conversion of dalvik failure format and error sun / misc / basecoder64 in Eclipse.

Instructions to solve the problem are:

    Install Windows XP sp2 with Java 6 or Ubuntu. Download adt version 23.0.2 with SDK 19.
    Decompress the adt and install it on your computer.
    Open the Eclipse as administrator and import the android file.
    In the file project.properties write this -> target = android-19 <-- very important.
    Export your project and this error will no more appear.