# Android: Conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1 ADT 2.1

Tags: android

This error during the export process is driving me crazy. It appeared after updating the ADT and adding ActionBarSherlock library, not sure which one is causing the trouble. I've already removed all the libraries and added them again, I've created a new project and copied the code over, didn't work either.

What other things can I try? (And don't tell me clean the project I've done that thousends of times)

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar/8106366#8106366 may be of some help

Comment: Unfortunately there are no <library>_src folders in my project. Like I said, I've really created a new project and copied the src and res folders and the manifest file to the new project, added two jars and the sherlock library but the error still showed up.

Comment: did you add abs as library project?

Comment: yes, is that wrong? It works perfectly when debugging, just exporting doesn't work

Comment: Nope it's right, I was just trying to figure out the problem

Comment: This is so strange: I changed the targetSdkVersion to 16 then it suddenly worked, then I changed it back to 17 and it didn't work and back again to 16 and again it didn't work. Then after having switched between 16 and 17 multiple times without success I changed back to 17, disable automatic building (no idea why but I was desperate) and it worked again. Then I cleaned the project and it didn't work again. But after disabling automatic building it works now all the time. This is the strangest thing I've ever experienced concerning computers...

Comment: I assume you are using eclipse :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This really sounds as though it can't be true but it works for me, so hopefully it also works for you if the problem isn't related to library linking stuff...

When you are in Eclipse, just turn off automatic build and then export without getting this error.

Comment: maaaan, I'm so calling my first born child Dominic!