# Error while running libgdx example

Tags: android, libgdx

I am new to libgdx.Just tried running the `libgdx` example i get strange error it says:

```
[2013-03-22 12:08:35 - ObjLoaderUsingLibGdx] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2013-03-22 12:08:35 - ObjLoaderUsingLibGdx] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
[2013-03-22 12:10:59 - ObjLoaderUsingLibGdx] Dx 
trouble processing "java/io/BufferedInputStream.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
```

I dont know what is the problem i have followed [this tutorial](http://chrismweb.com/2011/10/18/how-to-start-creating-android-games-using-the-libgdx-game-development-framework/) for getting started. can someone point out whats this error is all about. What can be the source of this error i am not able to understand followed all the steps out there imported all the lib and did build path as well

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetupNew. The link to set up your project.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=mmH05k6HFsI. A link to youtube with tutorial on how to setup ligdx.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/abxNKTFkuj8.

["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

Check if you have two JAR files on my buildpath that include the same package and classes. Remove one the package.

Try clean and build project.

Comment: As i said i am new to libgdx can you tell me what is this `nightly`. Have come across it but dont know whats the use of it. I am using ubuntu and eclipse for development and the libgdx version is 0.9.8.

Comment: And do i need to follow those steps to configure my app for libgdx. ? Cant i directly create application in eclipse and import all the library and do build path and get started with the project.

Comment: I got what is to be done. the problem was i was loading many library which were not useful and may be there it could have found double reference.Cleaned up my project and its up and running..!

Answer (score 0):

In my case Eclipse copied gdx-backend-gwt.jar in core project src, when I removed it, the problem has gone.