# Error Could not find apk

Tags: android

I am having error "[2013-08-17 12:17:28 - MainPageActivity] Could not find MainPageActivity.apk!". I am using the facebook SDK 3 and project target to 13.

```
target=android-13
android.library=true
android.library.reference.1=../../Facebook SDK/facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2/facebook
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You can try to open library project so it can't open

Comment: @AmitPrajapati I didn't get you. Please let me know in some detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the Following Steps

1. Restart Eclipse
2. Go to Project->Properties

   Select Android from left-hand side list

   Uncheck the "Is Library" checkbox
3. Remove R.Java file in gen folder

Comment: I am getting this error now `[2013-08-17 12:38:02 - MainPageActivity] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar