# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android + maven + eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I know there are a lot of stackoverflow questions regarding this subject.
But none of them seem to do it for me.
This is my pom.xml file: http://pastebin.com/00ne7fHA

I've unchecked the `Resolve dependencies for workspace projects` in the maven project properties

And when I try to run the application on the connected android device I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

If I check 'Maven dependencies' in `Build Path > Order and Export` and then try to run, I get the following console error:

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

If I then update the maven project, 'Maven Dependencies' in `Build Path > Order and Export` are unchecked and I'm back to square one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this thread "[Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)" on external Jar

see also: [Reason of Conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1](http://www.bimbima.com/health/post/2010/09/24/reason-of-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1.aspx)