# Eclipse bundling provided dependencies into apk

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I use eclipse for my android development and have a 32-bit Eclipse Juno setup where I can debug my android app via the emulator.  The android app uses maven for it's build and works properly.

I recently got a new laptop and installed the 64-bit version of Eclipse so I could increase the amount of memory available to it.  I have installed the same plugins (from what I can tell) and made a copy of my old workspace to make the transition easy.  However, when I try debug the android project I get

```
trouble processing javax/xml/namespace/QName.class
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

I've tracked the root cause of this error to the fact that eclipse is including the xpp jar into the apk even though it was marked as "provided" in my pom.

When I view the pom dependency heirarchy from the 64 bit install showing it as "provided" 
(don't have enough points to post a link to this)

But the libs view from the 64 bit install shows that it is getting exported anyway (bad)    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aslxf.png)

Finally, here is the libs view from the 32 bit eclipse install showing that it does NOT get exported (good, proper behavior)  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxR6X.png)

Been looking at this for awhile and am completley stumped as to why the 32 bit install works properly but the 64 bit one insists on exporting the provided jar.  I really thought copying the working workspace would solve it, but apparently there is something else going on here.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: READ: http://www.bimbima.com/health/post/2010/09/24/reason-of-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1.aspx AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my particular problem was to create an empty workspace, check the project out fresh from svn, and rebuild from scratch.

Apparently me cloning the old workspace did more harm than good.