# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1-in android ADT build v22.3.0-887826

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I am using Android ADT build V22.3.0-887826 for developing Android Application.In my application I am using external .jar file called `flanagan.jar`.I have added this .jar file in Referenced Libraries.In Editor view there was no error.But while running it in emulator it gives this error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

I solved this by clicking the checkbox near the added library (`flanagan.jar`) in `Properties->JavaBuildPath->Projects->Order and Export`.But now I am getting this error :

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

I tried the below link to fix this..

["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

But I cant remove that error.I dont know why this problem occurs.Please help me to fix this..I am new to Android..I googled this error so many times..I cant find proper solution

Comment: First remove all the `Third Party .jar` files and add all into `libs` folder and try to clean and built

Comment: Becoz here the main problem is `Conflict` your .jars file it's coming from your reference libraries and also from libs folder

Comment: @M D : In libs folder already there is a jar file named android-support-v4.jar...I cant add my Third Party .jar in libs folder..

Comment: @M D: No my jar file is not in lbs folder..Only in Referenced Libraried...

Comment: Anybody please solve this!!

Comment: try this by right clicking project and choose "Build Path -> Remove from Build Path" or in your project properties (Java Build Path -> Source tab).

Comment: @MD This is not available "Build Path -> Remove from Build Path"

Comment: @MD And what to do here Java Build Path -> Source tab

Comment: first remove your reference library and add again and clean and built

Comment: @MD i really done this..its in this link "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR which i posted

Comment: I still and cant solve this problem...Any other best solution??..

Comment: @MD I solved this by updating Java JDK

Answer (score 0):

You have added the jar file in a way that makes it visible is some areas and not in others. This inconsistency is what is causing your problem. To solve it, first remove it from your project - right-click on the project, go to Build Path -> Java Build Path, then go to the libraries tab. Here, click on the jar file, then click remove.

Before doing anything else, Clean the project, then build.

Now add back the jar file properly - copy it into the Libs folder inside your project (do this  using the File system, not Eclipse.

Back in Eclipse, again go the Libraries tab under Java Build Path, click on Add JARs... and add your jar file. Finally, go to the Order and Export tab and click the box next to the jar file. This final step is only necessary if you want to "export" the jar file so that other projects which depend on this project will be able to see the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

If the above solution doesn't help, an alternative cause of the "conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1" stems from the JAR file being compiled with a newer JDK version than what the Android Environment is configured.

i.e. Make sure you're not compiling the JAR file with JDK1.8 and using JDK 1.7 or lower as your compiler compliance level in your eclipse project configuration.