# Using boilerpipe on Android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, boilerpipe

I'm trying to use boilerpipe in an Android application.
I have included the libraries boilerpipe-1.2.0, nekohtml-1.9.13, xerces-2.9.1 in the libs folder.
When running the application with Eclipse i get the following error: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

It doesn't give me errors in the code. I'm also using the same code in a Java project and it works.
Could it be a problem of conflicts through dependencies?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

Comment: @Enry_h2o Did you manage to solve this? Having the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

The reason is dalvik uses different libraries than jvm.
I've created boilerpipe which uses correct ones: [boilerpipe-android](https://github.com/bldn/boilerpipe-android)