# Getting Error with crouton in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, dalvik, crouton

currently I´m getting a "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1". I already searched the web after solutions but did not find something that works for me. It seems to have something to do with the crouton library, that I´ve added in the past. I currently do not have installed the library. How can I fix / remove the Library?
Here is the error I get from the console:

*

> [2014-03-19 19:40:53 - UltimateCookbook] Conversion to Dalvik format
>   failed with error 1 [2014-03-19 19:41:45 - UltimateCookbook] Dx 
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name
>   (de/keyboardsurfer/android/widget/crouton/Configuration$1) does not
>   match path
>   (release/de/keyboardsurfer/android/widget/crouton/Configuration$1.class)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:520)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
>     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)    at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)     at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)    at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>     at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)  at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)   at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:187)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:786)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:597)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:733)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:328)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:403)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1143)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:155)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53) ...while
>   parsing
>   release/de/keyboardsurfer/android/widget/crouton/Configuration$1.class

*

When I am deleting the library in Windows myself, I only get more errors even if it is not used anymore (I think).

Comment: can you explain the problem properly ... I've also used this library... didnt got issue like this

Comment: Author of the library here. I can not confirm that this issue has anything to do with Crouton. Especially when you're not referencing it within your project.

Comment: I get this error very often when trying to export an APK. Try Project->Clean. If it doesn't work take a look at that thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar