# Dalvik conversion error due to StAX

Tags: java, android, dalvik

When I add the `stax-api-1.0-2.jar` in my Android project, I get the following error:

```
Dx trouble processing "javax/xml/stream/EventFilter.class"

Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Now I have searched the site and found this ["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar) and a lot of other similar questions and have tried out the solutions presented in them. Unfortunately, these solutions do not work for me. I have come to the conclusion that the problem is in using this jar itself.

My question is two-fold:

1. Why does Dalvik conversion fail when using particular core external jar like `stax-api-1.0-2.jar` but does not fail for `javax.json-1.0.4.jar`, `javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar`, `javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar` when these are also core jar files?
2. Which alternate to `stax-api-1.0-2.jar` I can use which will not cause this error?

Comment: Did you find solution for this issue?

Comment: @AidaIsay I did. You had to use the android jar instead of adding individual jars by yourself. This was a long time ago and this is all I remember.