# I am getting an error while exporting my code to an apk file ,it says Dalvik error 1?

Tags: android, apk

I have run the code on an android device , and everything is fine . Only when i try to export it displays the error message . The happen when i click on the final 'finish' button .
Thank You

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar

Answer (score 0):

Just disable automatic building in "Project/Build Automatically" and clean your project.