# Adding jar file cause Android project error: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Tags: java

I am using Eclipse for my programming. When I write programs in java project, everything was ok. Then, I copy a class to Android project and it is missing some imports:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
```

I search on google for the jar file and find out java-rt-jar-stubs-1.5.0.jar on website http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavartjarstubs150jar.htm

However, when I add the library in project (Right click on project -> Build path -> Configure build path -> Java Build Path -> Tab Libraries (added needed libraries) and Tab Order and Export (check on those libraries)), it cause me an error: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1.

Does anyone knows how to fix it? Please help me!

Comment: yes.. You *most probably* have a conflict condition.. Check if there are multiple Jars (usually third party Jars) with the same class or incompatible JAR(s).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I check the libraries, there is only one file jar name: java-rt-jar-stubs-1.5.0.jar. When I remove it, the error do not display anymore. I guess that in android project, we cannot use those imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no ImageIO or AWT libraries available for Android and I don't think you can add them with `java-rt-jar-stubs-1.5.0.jar` (what is it BTW?). You will likely need to convert the code to use standard imaging classes provided by Android, like `BitmapFactory` and `Bitmap`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will try to replace BufferedImage with Bitmap :D

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments section , this most probably occurs due to conflicts in jars (same class names or package names inside different jars).. Please check this thread: 
["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

Comment: I tried the solution in this web but it did not solve my problem. Anyway, thank you for your comment :D