# Gradle cant compile with libs

Tags: java, android, jar

I have created a Jar in Intellij. Jar contains following folder.file:....

1. okio
2. meta-inf->maven
3. com ->
   google,
   squareup,
   xyz,

I am trying to use the Jar in Android project. After compilation it gives following error in android studio:....

```
**Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:preDexDebug
 UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing com/abc/xyz/Filename.class
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 2.741 secs
>   Information:1 error**

My build.gadle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.livquik.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile files('libs/JavaJar.jar')
}
```

Comment: May I know the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662801/bad-class-file-magic-or-version) link for  **bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version** error in android studio.better you can get the right solution

Answer (score 0):

1.) Custom .jar files you are creating in eclipse are tricky. I had a number of files being read from within the jar. Moving these files away from the main folder of the jar file is a good idea (i.e. Do not place them at the same folder level as the folders: com, Meta-inf). I moved mine into the same place as the actual compiled class files.

---

2.) When compiling the .jar file, make sure you change the compiler to JRE 1.6. Compiling with this setting was also a factor that led to my eventual success.

**TO CHANGE COMPILER COMPLIANCE:**

In Eclipse, right-click on your project. Click on properties (it should be near the bottom of the right-click box). In the properties dialog box, select **Java Compiler** from the list on the left. You may need to uncheck **Use compliance from Execution environment...** in order for the drop down box to become enabled. Change the **Compiler Compliance Level** to 1.6, click apply and ok.

**FINALLY**

Recompile, re-copy and import the library into your android project and hopefully that should fix it.