# Getting UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION in android studio

Tags: java, android, signalr

I have only java version 1.8.0_45 (`jdk1.8.0_45`). So, your suggested solution's not solve my problem.

When I `Run` the app it throws the following errors:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
>       at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
>       at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
>       at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
>       at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
>       ... 12 more
>   1 error; aborting
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Here is the my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
//    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0'
    compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android-release.jar')
}
```

I also tried to add the `signalr-client-sdk-android-release` lib as `.aar` file. But the result's same.

So, why this exception throws? And how can I solve problem *for this project*?

Thanks.

Comment: how is this not a dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662801/bad-class-file-magic-or-version

Comment: @MarcB thanks for your quick response. But result is same. I also tried it before.

Comment: Try using jar files in my GitHub sample project https://github.com/ngocchung/SimpleSignalRClient/tree/master/app/libs to see if it can help or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `signalr-client-sdk.jar` causes this exception. So, these steps solved my problem:

1. Created new project
2. Imported (`.java`) source files of `signalr-client-sdk` from its folder ([link to files](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client/tree/master/signalr-client-sdk/src/main/java/microsoft/aspnet/signalr/client)).
3. Imported `signalr-client-sdk-android-release.aar` as module.
4. **DON'T CHANGE** any configuration in `build.gradle` files.

That's it.

Thank you.