# Can not compile gradle project because of facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook

Try to integrate facebook sdk in my app, add maven in build.gradle
`repositories {
    mavenCentral() 
}`

and sdk

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.2'
```

and while build project i got

```
Error:cannot access Utility$3
  bad class file: pocket-android1\generic\hotelClient\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.facebook.android\facebook-android-sdk\4.8.1\jars\classes.jar(com/facebook/internal/Utility$3.class)
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Comment: rebuild it once....this is the correct way only

Comment: @gvsharma already did it, but doesn't help

Comment: What is android SDK? try to compile with other SDKs and it will be helping you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662801/bad-class-file-magic-or-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it will help but try compiling another version of Facebook SDK. For example, 4.7.0. I have no problem with that one.