# Android Parse Exception when I build

Tags: android, exception, httpserver, parseexception

I am developing an app for my family business and I can't figure out what the source of this build time error is?

```
Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (BaseHTTPServer$py) does not match path (Lib/BaseHTTPServer$py.class)
```

I tried cleaning the project, deleting the /app/build folder as I was told elsewhere on the internet, and I tried to reset all my changes. Any help on what maybe causing this error and/or how to fix it would be great.

Edit 1: I am trying to use the Jython Library (http://www.jython.org/)

Edit 2: After retracing my steps it is now fixed.

Thanks and have a great day!

-Fisch

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be an issue with Jython. Removing it from the libs folder and the reference solved the issue.

Comment: I am having the same problem, may I ask if you are removing the whole jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar from the libs folder and put it under the app dir?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663045

It might be related to you using the java 8 JDK as your JDK for compiling.

Try switching it to the java 7 JDK.

Comment: Ok I tried to change the JDK to 7 and I still have the same error. Also I am trying to use the Jython Library (http://www.jython.org/)