# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000) android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm developing an android app in which I imported a pure java library as a jar file, after which when I am trying to run the app it gives me 2 errors,

```
1. UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:569)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
... 12 more
2 errors; aborting

2.* What went wrong:
   Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program    Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I tried adding apply plugin: 'java'
but no luck

Also exported jar with jdk 1.8.0_20 an using the same version in android studio

Build.gradel

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "in.automator.automator"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
}dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile files('src/main/java/in/automator/automator/marf.jar')}
```

settings.gradel

```
include ':app'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bad class file magic or version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662801/bad-class-file-magic-or-version)

Comment: @toolkit I already mentioned in question that I tried apply plugin: 'java'

Comment: your `automator/marf` is likely to be compiled for java 8. recompile for java 7

Comment: @njzk2 can you guide me how to do this in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings.gradle and build.gradle files, and see if you have included the reference twice.

Comment: please check the gradel files in question.