# Adding plain java lib .jar to Android project throws bad class file magic or version

Tags: java, android, jar

So I have an **executable Android project**, it runs and works well.
I have made a **library for it, separate project, only using java, not Android framework.**

No I would like to make a **.jar from my library and add it to my Android Proejct.**

I have made it so far, but when I run it I get the following error:

**in short:**

> Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file
>   magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)

[In long.](http://pastebin.com/uJEsLYDZ)

I have added the .jar dependency to my gradle file: (It is the task_server_core.jar)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/task_server_core.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
}
```

**And both projects made with java 1.8.0_45**

What m I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bad class file magic or version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662801/bad-class-file-magic-or-version)

Comment: You are using Java 8 on Android, that's what's wrong.

Comment: @cricket_007 Should I just change to java 7 for both projects and do it again and it should work?

Comment: I don't have your jar file, but it's worth trying. There are a few things in that link you can do, also

Answer (score 0):

Changed both Android project's and java lib project's JAVA version to 1.7 solved the problem.