# Using Kotlogram library in android project

Tags: java, android, telegram

I want to use [Kotlogram library](https://github.com/badoualy/kotlogram)  in my android project.

Im using java 7 (jdk1.7.0_79). but when I want to debug or run the project, this error is happened:

> > UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
> >         java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
> >         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
> >         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
> >         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
> >         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
> >         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
> >         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
> >         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
> >         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
> >         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
> >         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
> >         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
> >         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
> >         at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
> >         Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: **bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)**
> >         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
> >         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
> >         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
> >         at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
> >         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
> >         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
> >         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
> >         at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
> >         ... 12 more
> >         1 error; aborting
> >     FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

app build.gradel content:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "api.telegram.learn.kotlogram"
    minSdkVersion 12
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   
       'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
dexOptions {

}
}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.github.badoualy:kotlogram:0.0.6'
}
```

project build.gradel content

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: add this in your gradle and clean and rebuild your project..  above the dependence sectioin. <br> repositories {
  
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bad class file magic or version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662801/bad-class-file-magic-or-version)

Comment: I show my app build.gradel content in this post. i forget to show the project build.gradel too. ofcourse I have added this repository. I have added this repository in the project build.gradel. I dont have compile error. this error happen when i want to debug or run the project

Comment: i saw this link "Bad class file magic or version ". but it does not help me

Comment: can anyone help me?  I must solve this error

Comment: You need Java 8. Android works with Java 8 if you enable the Jack compiler.

Answer (score -1):

finally i download the repository and add its module manually to the android project and find the problem.

only java 8 can compile and run these moudels correctly. they use some special method that are defined in java 8 but not in java 7. java 7 can not compile them.

by looking at this [refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development),  android project need java 7 for compiling and running.

it seem that using Kotlogram in android project is impossible.

Comment: That's not true. Java 8 works with Android perfectly fine when Jack is enabled.

Comment: what do you mean about Jack?

Comment: please suggest some link, to learn more about using java 8 in  android.