# Execution failed for task ':preDexDebug'

Tags: android, gradle

The project has dependence on a library, but another solutions from the site doesn't help. Tried everything stackoverflow suggested on this problem. Who can decode for me the following exception and where does it comes from ?

```
:preDexDebug
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\t... 12 more","sources":[{}]}
    AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"1 error; aborting","sources":[{}]}


     FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':preDexDebug'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is originating from the inner exception `com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)`.

There is already a large thread about this here: [Bad class file magic or version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662801/bad-class-file-magic-or-version)