# New eclipse Android project can't build

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dalvik

Error dump : http://pastebin.com/mpiV8qZr

I'm not sure what exactly causes this, the eclipse installation is fresh, I'm using :

Eclipse for Android Developers
Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800

Just created a new Android project, tried to debug it to make the .apk, but I get this error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like you just started on the project. Shift to android studio and feel the comfort of designing android apps. Thanks

Comment: I would but, I'm not making the app here, to be very specific : I have to use eclipse to create a native .jar plugin for Unity3D to be able to get callbacks from overriding native methods like onActivityResult()

Comment: I belive, same is possible with studio too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24663045/1811348

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
Try to create a new

```
Android Application Project
```

instead of

```
Android Project
```

It works for me.