# ParseException in android build

Tags: android

I am getting following error while building android app, and I have googled this error and many people suggested to downgrade/revert to Java 1.7 which is not possible for me. Any other ways to address this issue?

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:505)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:244)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing com/google/devtools/build/android/desugar/runtime/ThrowableExtension.class
```

Comment: So, if you are running an older version of Java, those are no longer actively supported for bug and security patches, so no other way than to use Java 7 or (much higher).

Comment: We already using JAVA8, I can not use JAVA 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bad class file magic or version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662801/bad-class-file-magic-or-version)