# Deleted my Project Folder, re-imported, and now my project is full of errors

Tags: android

I had my application almost working, but it would not run due to some strange error “Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1”. I found this thread (["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top)) and saw a suggestion to delete then re-import. So I copied the project to another folder and deleted it from the current workspace. Now I've imported it back and am getting all kinds of "cannot be resolved" errors. Many of my xml files also have errors. Please help.

Comment: I think I've fixed it. When importing before, I didn't have "copy projects into workspace checked". I did this time and all is well. What a relief.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use "copy projects into workspace checked" when import projects,if still the errors are there select the imported libraries in your project -> right click -> select build path-> select remove from build path.Once it run properly you can add the libraries again.