# "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 ",

Tags: java, android

Getting this error when I try to run my Android application. I've tried everything in here: ["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

Here are screenshots of my project folder:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SBuW.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMD5E.png

Here's the message I get:

```
[2014-08-07 02:56:26 - Activity2] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$6) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-08-07 02:56:29 - Activity2] Dx 
trouble processing "javax/transaction/HeuristicCommitException.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

[2014-08-07 02:56:29 - Activity2] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2014-08-07 02:56:29 - Activity2] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

I have no idea what's going on. I'm a noob to Android programming and none of the suggested fixes that I've seen has worked. I've seen someone mention something about making a different package and moving the .jar files there. I did that and got the same error.

Comment: Why have you added all those libraries? What do you need them for? Most of them look unsuitable for an android app.

Comment: Trying to use Youtube API v3. Just imported everything that was in a folder I found online. The one on google's site gave me a 404 error when I tried to download. Maybe I should try removing all that are not listed under "Android" [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#Maven)? Do you think that would work?

Comment: Remove everything, then add them one by one as you need them, checking whether the app still builds after each. If the jar has any of the words logging, servlet, jetty, appengine you almost certainly don't need it.

Comment: When you say remove, can I just delete them from the libs folder or do I have to go into the Java build path as well?

Comment: So I did what you told me to do and now I'm having import issues. Can't find classes in three java files in my project.

Comment: Put back my old files and now I have errors that I didn't have before.

Comment: Finally got it back to giving me the original error. Thanks...I guess.