# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 Weird error in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm getting a weird error in LibGDX when I'm trying to compile my android game.

```
[2015-01-30 12:20:39 - Pong-android] Dx 7 errors; aborting
[2015-01-30 12:20:39 - Pong-android] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

People are saying double jar files can cause this where do I find these jar files? It always worked fine and I didn't edit my project folder. I looked over alot stackoverflow posts about this error but I just can't figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this thread:

["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

More information available here:

[Reason of Conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1](http://bimbim.in/post/2010/09/24/Reason-of-Conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1.aspx)

And please don't hesitate to use search first.