# TOP LEVEL EXCEPTION on Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, jaxb

Im trying to build my android project. This project uses methods from another project (API) which contains property JAXB methods to marshall and unmarshall. I added the project api as .jar with jersey and gson libraries in my android project and it always shows the "Conversion to Dalvik format failed".
This is the log:

```
[2015-03-30 18:29:28 - HolaCampus] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (com/theoryinpractise/halbuilder/jaxrs/HalUnmarshallerTest) does not match path (target/test-classes/com/theoryinpractise/halbuilder/jaxrs/HalUnmarshallerTest.class)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:520)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:188)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:786)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:597)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:328)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:403)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1143)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:155)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
...while parsing target/test-classes/com/theoryinpractise/halbuilder/jaxrs/HalUnmarshallerTest.class

[2015-03-30 18:29:28 - HolaCampus] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2015-03-30 18:29:28 - HolaCampus] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

I have read another posts with similar errors and i tried this possible solutions without lucky: 
1- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24230984/4230181

```
Right click to your project, select properties.
A dialog will show up, select 'Java build path' on the left menu.
Remove 'Android dependencies' and 'Android private libraries' on the right panel then click OK
Clean your project (select menu Project --> Clean)
Right click your project, select Android Tools -> Fix project properties
Clean project once again.
Restart your computer
Open eclipse and Export apk
```

2- Go to Project » Properties » Java Build Path » Libraries and remove all except the "Android X.Y" (in my case Android 1.5). click OK. Go to Project » Clean » Clean projects selected below » select your project and click OK. That should work.

3- In this case, when i export the apk shows the same error with conversion to dalvik.

```
Go to Project -> uncheck Build Automatically

Go to Project -> Clean... , clean both the library project and your app project

Export your app as a signed APK while Build Automatically is still disabled
```

What do you think about this? I dont know what more can i to try. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Solution:
1- Erase all imports from build path. 
2- Copy manually all .jar files in to the /libs directory.
3- Erase all jaxrs .jars from /libs.
4- Refresh the project.
5- Run the project.
6- Enjoy!

Comment new problem. :(

Comment: This last solved the problem. However, on execution time (and before the warnings) the app does not find the classes,which contains into the imported .jars. It shows "NoclassdeffFound" on runtime and before the runtime "Failed resolving <class".