# Error in Eclipse after serially building apk

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse to build an Android apk (by exporting as Android application). However, if the same project is exported again after the first successful build, an error will be shown in the Export Wizard window with message "**Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1**". On the other hand, if the Eclipse is closed and re-opened, the export will succeed. Such behavior seems like a bug. Does anyone have the same problem?

p.s.: The reason why the same project is built twice is that I want to check if the resulting apk is always the same, since I noticed that sometimes the apk from a successful build will cause crash after uploading to Google Play. However, I find some variation in the file size (about several hundred KB) among each successful build. Due to the strange problem mentioned above, I need to close the Eclipse and re-open it to obtain one build result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar

Comment: @siva35 I've read the thread before. However I think the root cause is different since the building error only occurs after the first successful build while no change is even made.