# Android Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Tags: android, eclipse, dalvik

This is a follow up question to this question: ["Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" on external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar)

I got an Android project using Eclipse. When trying to run the application I get this error:

> [2016-11-03 12:12:50 - MyProject] Dx unsupported class file version 52.0 ...while parsing android/UnusedStub.class
>
> [2016-11-03 12:12:50 - MyProject] Dx 1 error; aborting
>
> [2016-11-03 12:12:50 - MyProject] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

I read that it might be a JRE issue but I'm using jre 7 and set the Java compiler in the project's properties to work with compliance to JavaSe-1.7.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the .jar file you have problems with? I had a similar issue when adding an Apache library, xerces.jar and I removed it and then unzipped the .jar file and added as a separate package and then it worked.

Comment: Im working with several jars but none of them in particular caused it I think.. Im just trying to run the app

Comment: IMO, it's a .jar file causing the error and you got to find the one which is causing.

Comment: How can I find something like this? If I remove a jar, the project won't compile.

Comment: Try searching by names of the .jar files and you might get a hunch of what file you should remove.

Comment: android/UnusedStub.class belongs to Google Play Services which I use... so?