# Android Compile issues in RSA 8.0.1 (Eclipse 3.6) - NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/x509/X500Name

Tags: android, eclipse, rational-rsa

I installed the ADT plugin for eclipse smoothly. When I created my first Android project, right off the bat, I got the compile error below. I found that the `sun/security/x509/X500Name` is in the rt.jar so I tried adding that to my build path, but this causes the project to eat a lot of memory while compiling (I find this unusual). Has anyone been able to solve this issue? I'm using jdk1.6.0_24. I've seen other vague posts out there saying I need to use the Sun JDK. I'm already using that and I already have that in my JAVA_HOME. I'd appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/x509/X500Name
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.writeSignatureBlock(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.close(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.sealApk(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.finalPackage(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.finalDebugPackage(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android/9916751#9916751

I had the same problem and the link above fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The not found class is used by SignedJarBuilder of the Android SDK. A solution could be not to use the signing of Android SDK, but to sign the created .apk separately, by the [jarsigner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/jarsigner.html) command.

I did the signing using Maven - http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/SigningAPKWithMavenJarsigner.

You can specify the debug signing in the following way:

```
   <keystore>
    ${user.home}${file.separator}.android${file.separator}debug.keystore
   </keystore>
   <storepass>android</storepass>
   <keypass>android</keypass>
   <alias>androiddebugkey</alias>
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed a stand-alone Eclipse 3.6 IDE (Helios) and it worked like a charm. Based on this, I've come to the conclusion that this will never work with IBM's RSA 8.0.1 (Even though it is based on Eclipse 3.6).