# Using Zxing Library in my aplication

Tags: android-studio, barcode, zxing

I have seriously tried to find a method to integrate zxing library for my barcode scanning application and found some examples and tutorials, but they mostly concentrate on the code of integrating the project library. I have understood how to use it but my only issue is I cant seem to find a correct way to copy the new zxing library. Please can anyone guide me through which files to copy where or how to bind the project in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to 'add' the zxing library in your Android Studio project.
If you are comfortable with using Gradle, just add the below line in your app's build.gradle file under dependencies.

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
```

Build your project and then start integrating zxing by importing the required classes.

I hope this answers your question and solves your problem.

Comment: I tried copying the entire project and using the compile statement but it gives error at 'android' in the import statement of the import statement               import com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.cameraManager;       import com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.FrontLightMannager;                     also cannot resolve CameraManager

Comment: That seems to be strange. You do NOT need to copy anything into your project, just adding the compile statement and building your project should do. Gradle does all the heavy lifting of downloading libraries and managing dependencies for you. If you have followed the above process and still unable to import your classes, the problem should be in your gradle. Let me know if you find any errors while building your project after adding the compile statement.

Comment: I followed the instructions given here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156399/how-to-decode-a-barcode-from-camera-preview-using-zxing-library-in-android/30628337#30628337                                                                                      by the user:user2904625    and after adding the dependencies and compile statements i get errors in cameramanager.class captureactivity.class and so many more with symbol class not found error statements.( error: cannot find symbol class PlanarYUVLuminanceSource) i have added module android of the zxing master project library