# NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType for zxing

Tags: android, zxing, noclassdeffounderror, barcode-scanner

I am developing an application to scan barcode on Android by ZXing.
I follow this [tutorial](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/12/tutorial-65-implement-barcode-scanner-using-zxing-in-android/).

But when I run my application, NoClassDefFoundError got and application finished.

```
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391): Process: com.foxconn.cnsbg.it.barcodescanner, PID: 10391
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/zxing/ResultMetadataType;
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.<clinit>(CaptureActivity.java:93)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.foxconn.cnsbg.it.barcodescanner-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    ... 15 more
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):        ... 16 more
08-06 10:42:43.401: E/AndroidRuntime(10391):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I had searched around Google and fix my Build path in CaptureActivity project like:
[image]

and also add core-2.2.jar into **libs** folder of both CaptureActivity project and my project. How should I fix this problem?

Comment: either add it to your build path or include the jar into libs...not both and for godsake use studio

Comment: I have fixed as your advice, but still got this

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this post:
[Updating sdk got NoClassDefFoundError  for zxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889737/updating-sdk-got-noclassdeffounderror-for-zxing)

Quoting Till

"I didn't have to put the jar-library in assets or lib(s), but only tick the box for this jar in Properties -> Java Build Path -> "Order and Export" (it was listed before, but not selected)

You might have to do a project > clean after this to take effect!"

That works for me!

Answer (score 1):

`NoClassDefFoundError` occurs when there is a class file that your code depends on and it is present at compile time but not found at runtime.

Since classes present inside `core-2.2.jar` are the base of your application, for consistency, you would like to add this dependency into your lib folder instead of providing this externally to the build path.

Also check for differences in your build time and runtime `classpath`. A quick check on this should resolve your problem.

Comment: I had put core-2.2.jar into libs folder instead of providing externally to the build path and problem not fixed :(

Comment: Does your code execute outside of Eclipse using command line `javac` & `java`?

Comment: No, I execute by Run As/Android Application on Eclipse and run application on my android phone

Comment: Is this `core-2.2.jar` part of your `.apk` file which get executed on the device?

Comment: Hm, Sorry I am a newbie, but how to check this?

Comment: Try to move `core-2.2.jar` to the bottommost position in order & export tab of your above screenshot.

Comment: Check Project -> Libraries, in your favourite IDE. If usinng maven, mvn clean install can update that.