# Android airpush error

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement Airpush for android into my app but even for the original test sample app logcat says

```
dalvikvm    Could not find class 'com.airpush.android.Airpush', referenced from method com.air.airtest.onCreate
```

and my code is from the original sample code so no parsing error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are using new Eclipse ADT.

If you have references to jars that are not in the ‘libs’ folder, for example if you use ‘classpath variable’, you can resolve the NoClassDefFoundError issue with the new ADT 17 by exporting the references. To export the references: simply go to “Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export”, and check all the references you want exported.  After successful completion of all the steps Clean &Build the project. See the picture below.
 Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android) for more deatils.