# How to added customed jar into my android project ? (I added core.jar into my android project but still class not find exception.)

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, zxing

I have downloaded Zxing Barcode Scanner code for android.
I added core.jar into my android project build It is can compile but when it run on stimulator still for missing class error
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType
When I added all source code of code into my project src there is no more that error

If I want added I defined jar packet into android project how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Tick the box for this jar in Properties -> Java Build Path -> "Order and Export" (it was listed before, but not selected)

as answered here: 
[NoClassDefFoundError - Eclipse and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android/10140763#10140763)