# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on android

Tags: java, android

i am doing an application-email sending without user interaction. so that i got coding from the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124). here i got **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**: com.murali.email.GMailSender. i got this error at

```
GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("username@gmail.com", "password");
                    sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                            "This is Body",   
                            "user@gmail.com",   
                            "user@yahoo.com");
```

in the MailSenderActivity Class. i added all external jars in referenced library  and no error found at compile time. i spent more time to solve the issue but failed. i know it is possible of duplicate question but the other answers were not used for me. i guess me or eclipse miss some jar or class path for GMailSender class. please help me. i do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Does GMailSender come from an other Eclipse project as a library project / external jar? If yes, set that project to export the jar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure the jar sits in a folder named libs, not lib. Then perform "clean" and make sure the jar appears under Android dependencies.

Comment: You are wrong. When using the latest ADT it seems that jar files in `lib` won't get included under Android dependencies, and it can cause the above exception.

Comment: Here is a thread about the subject -
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android)

Comment: Even in that question there are many answers stating they solved the problem without moving the jars

Comment: thanks, i created a new project with libs folder now its works!

Comment: Of course there are many other ways to "achieve" `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`... but the last ADT upgrade surly contributed its part and I think it better to deny this case before proceeding any further

Answer (score 2):

If we get this error on android

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler  referenced from method javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders

We need to add `aditional.jar` along with `mail.jar` and `activation.jar`. This solved my issue in android when accessing MimeMultipart.