# Using the com.loopj.android.http library causes java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: http, asynchronous

I have tried uses-library clause but that gives me this error : **Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY**

I tried adding the library android-async-http-1.3.2.jar to both the lib folder and as a user library. There are no compile time errors but during run time it doesn't seem to find the library for some strange reason.

This is the error log :

06-01 14:29:57.073: E/AndroidRuntime(5354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 14:29:57.073: E/AndroidRuntime(5354): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams
06-01 14:29:57.073: E/AndroidRuntime(5354):     at  com.android.myprojectname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jar file should be in the `libs` folder not the `lib` folder, try that.

Also, make sure you are importing the classes for use in your code:

```
import com.loopj.android.http.*;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Although I found the answer before I read this over here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android , but Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

Check that `.jar` is checked in the tab `"Order and Export"` in the window `"Java build path"`.

If it doesn't work, add your folder `"libs"` in `"Source"` tab.