# Greendao-orm database locked error

Tags: android, greendao

I've got locket database error using greendao. I use correct the libraries, everything worked for a while, but suddenly I receive the following:
*(I have HTC Desire with JB 4.2.2. AOPK)*
NoClassDefFoundError

> 05-21 19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-21 19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.schonherz.dbentities.DaoMaster
>   05-21 19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):   at
>   com.schonherz.dbentities.DaoMaster$OpenHelper.onCreate(DaoMaster.java:69)
>   05-21 19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
>   05-21 19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
>   05-21 19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):   at
>   com.schonherz.flottadroid.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:95)
>   05-21 19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 05-21
>   19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   05-21 19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
>   05-21 19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
>   05-21 19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150) 05-21
>   19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
>   05-21 19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 05-21
>   19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 05-21 19:45:47.639:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9715):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195) 05-21
>   19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-21
>   19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 05-21 19:45:47.639:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9715):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
>   05-21 19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562) 05-21
>   19:45:47.639: E/AndroidRuntime(9715):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Here is my activity:

```java
package com.schonherz.flottadroid;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.schonherz.classes.JsonArrayToArrayList;
import com.schonherz.classes.JsonFromUrl;
import com.schonherz.classes.NetworkUtil;
import com.schonherz.classes.SessionManager;
import com.schonherz.dbentities.AutoDao;
import com.schonherz.dbentities.AutoKepDao;
import com.schonherz.dbentities.DaoMaster;
import com.schonherz.dbentities.DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper;
import com.schonherz.dbentities.DaoSession;
import com.schonherz.dbentities.MunkaDao;
import com.schonherz.dbentities.MunkaEszkozDao;
import com.schonherz.dbentities.MunkaKepDao;
import com.schonherz.dbentities.MunkaTipusDao;
import com.schonherz.dbentities.PartnerDao;
import com.schonherz.dbentities.PartnerKepDao;
import com.schonherz.dbentities.ProfilKepDao;
import com.schonherz.dbentities.Sofor;
import com.schonherz.dbentities.SoforDao;
import com.schonherz.dbentities.SoforDao.Properties;
import com.schonherz.dbentities.TelephelyDao;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

// Handle first start from preference
SharedPreferences preferences;
long firstStart;

// Database Handlers
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private DevOpenHelper helper;
private DaoSession daoSession;
private DaoMaster daoMaster;

// Greendao objects
private AutoDao autoDao;
private AutoKepDao autoKepDao;
private MunkaDao munkaDao;
private MunkaEszkozDao munkaEszkozDao;
private MunkaKepDao munkaKepDao;
private MunkaTipusDao munkaTipusDao;
private PartnerDao partnerDao;
private PartnerKepDao partnerKepDao;
private ProfilKepDao profilKepDao;
private SoforDao soforDao;
private TelephelyDao telephelyDao;



private SessionManager sessionManager;
private boolean isRefreshed;


Button loginButton;
ProgressDialog dialog;

EditText userEditText;
EditText passEditText;

Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    context=getApplicationContext();
    sessionManager=new SessionManager(context);
    isRefreshed=false;

    helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this, "flotta-db", null);
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
    daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();

    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    firstStart = preferences.getLong("firstStart", 0);

    userEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUser);
    passEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPass);

    userEditText.setText("sofor1");
    passEditText.setText("sofor1");

    // First start, full DB init, get soforTable
    if (firstStart == 0) {

        createTables();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putLong("firstStart", 1);
        editor.commit();
        editor = null;

        if (NetworkUtil.checkInternetIsActive(context) == false) {

            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_internet, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    } else {
        // Get a Session and init sofor Table


        soforDao = daoSession.getSoforDao();
    }

        // If internet connection OK, drop sofor Table and get new table
        if (NetworkUtil.checkInternetIsActive(context) == true) {

            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPreExecute();
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                    if (result == true) {
                        isRefreshed=true;
                        loginButton.setEnabled(true);
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                                R.string.refreshed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();                            
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.errorRefresh, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return saveSoforTable();
                }

            }.execute();
        }


    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEntry);
    loginButton.setEnabled(false);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Start main activity
            if (checkLogin() == true) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("isRefreshed", isRefreshed);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                LoginActivity.this.finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                        R.string.wrongCredential, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

        }
    });
}

public boolean saveSoforTable() {
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    JSONObject json;

    String serverAddres = "http://www.flotta.host-ed.me/querySoforTable.php";

    json = new JSONObject();

    try {

        jsonArray = (JSONArray) JsonFromUrl.getJsonObjectFromUrl(
                serverAddres, json.toString());

        // Eldobjuk a tablat es ujra letrehozzuk
        soforDao.dropTable(soforDao.getDatabase(), true);
        soforDao.createTable(soforDao.getDatabase(), true);


        ArrayList<Sofor> soforok = JsonArrayToArrayList
                .JsonArrayToSofor(jsonArray);

        for (int i = 0; i < soforok.size(); i++) {
            soforDao.insert(soforok.get(i));                
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    }


}

@Override
public void finish() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
}

// Tabla letrehozo metodus, elso inditaskor mindekepp lefut
private void createTables() {

    autoDao = daoSession.getAutoDao();
    autoKepDao = daoSession.getAutoKepDao();
    munkaDao = daoSession.getMunkaDao();
    munkaEszkozDao = daoSession.getMunkaEszkozDao();
    munkaKepDao = daoSession.getMunkaKepDao();
    munkaTipusDao = daoSession.getMunkaTipusDao();
    partnerDao = daoSession.getPartnerDao();
    partnerKepDao = daoSession.getPartnerKepDao();
    profilKepDao = daoSession.getProfilKepDao();
    soforDao = daoSession.getSoforDao();
    telephelyDao = daoSession.getTelephelyDao();

    autoDao.createTable(db, true);
    autoKepDao.createTable(db, true);
    munkaDao.createTable(db, true);
    munkaEszkozDao.createTable(db, true);
    munkaKepDao.createTable(db, true);
    munkaTipusDao.createTable(db, true);
    partnerDao.createTable(db, true);
    partnerKepDao.createTable(db, true);
    profilKepDao.createTable(db, true);
    soforDao.createTable(db, true);
    telephelyDao.createTable(db, true);

}

public String update() {
    return "";
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}   

public boolean checkLogin() {
    if (!userEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        if (!passEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) {

            // Ez csak bemutatato, a loadAll() az a select * from
            List<Sofor> sofors = soforDao.loadAll();

            // Where-ben 2 feltetellel lekerdezes, a Properties az a
            // SoforDao properties osztalya importalva
            // Minden tablanak van minden rekordjara egy property, amihez
            // lehet hasonlita
            List<Sofor> soforok = soforDao
                    .queryBuilder()
                    .where(Properties.SoforLogin.eq(userEditText.getText()
                            .toString()),
                            Properties.SoforPass.eq(passEditText.getText()
                                    .toString())).list();

            if (soforok.size() > 0) {
                sessionManager.createLoginSession(soforok.get(0).getSoforLogin(), soforok.get(0).getSoforPass(), soforok.get(0).getSoforID());
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.wrongCredential,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.wrongCredential,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NoClassDefFoundError - Eclipse and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android)

This topic helped me out, I had an ADT update before this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to open up multiple connections to the database at once. Make sure that you only have one connection running at a time (I believe your onCreate function gets called multiple times since you're probably switching from app to app). Better move your initialization to the constructor or so.