# NoClassDefFoundError: com.sforce.soap.enterprise.Connector

Tags: java, android, soap, salesforce, soql

I am trying to query contacts from salesForce account but getting above error.

I generated `enterprise.jar` file from the WSDL downloaded from my account.

I have `wsc-23-min.jar` along with `enterprise.jar` files in `libs` folder.

Below method is used to query contacts

```
private void queryContacts() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Querying for the 5 newest Contacts...");

    ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
    config.setUsername("***@***.com");
    config.setPassword("***");

    try {

        connection = Connector.newConnection(config);
        // query for the 5 newest contacts      
        com.sforce.soap.enterprise.QueryResult queryResults = connection.query("SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Account.Name " +
                "FROM Contact WHERE AccountId != NULL ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 5");

        if (queryResults.getSize() > 0) {
            for (int i=0;i<queryResults.getRecords().length;i++) {
                // cast the SObject to a strongly-typed Contact
                Contact c = (Contact)queryResults.getRecords()[i];
                Log.i(TAG, " ------------- Id: " + c.getId() + " - Name: "+c.getFirstName()+" "+
                        c.getLastName()+" - Account: "+c.getAccount().getName());
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any help or clue is appreciated.
Thanks.

**Edit:**

I tried all the methods from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android) popular question but no luck.

I have other projects in my workspace which are having jar files (in 'libs' folder) and they all work properly. Don’t know whats wrong with salesforce related jar files.

**Edit:**

There is no problem with `wsc-23.jar` file. Classes placed in this jar, for ex. `Connector` and others loading and they are working fine.

Only problem is with generated `enterprise.jar` through WSDL file.

Followed [this](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_quickstart_steps.htm) to generate enterprise.jar file

Not getting what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution for my problem.

[Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22498/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-sforce-soap-enterprise-connector) is a link for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should place your jar in `libs` folder not in `lib` folder. After that goto Project properties and add the jar to `java build path`.

Comment: Sorry. I edited my question. All jars are in libs folder only. NOT in lib. Even I follwed http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17 post but no luck.

Comment: Are your jars appear in `Referenced Libraries`?

Comment: Yes. They r appearing.

Comment: Possibly there may be something wrong with Order and export.Make sure your all custom libraries are below `YOURPROJECT/gen` and all are checked.

Comment: All jars r below proj/gen folder. I was missing "checking" part but after doing that also no luck.

Comment: did you clean your project after that?