# NoClassDefFoundError in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

So essentially I've been making a game using libgdx and just recently I started to try and add Google Play Game Services and So I tried my hand at it and it seems as though I have completely messed up my `.xml` file I've tried looking at questions such as [How do I resolve this Java Class not found exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408769/how-do-i-resolve-this-java-class-not-found-exception) and [NoClassDefFoundError - Eclipse and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android), but to no avail.

Here is the runtime error I am recieving.

```
02-19 19:25:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(25746): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 19:25:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(25746): Process: com.coppercow.minerman, PID: 25746
02-19 19:25:17.772: E/AndroidRuntime(25746): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.coppercow.minerman/com.coppercow.minerman.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.coppercow.minerman.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.coppercow.minerman-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.coppercow.minerman-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

The class Name is MainActivity.Java and it is in the src file. I understand that this is done because of one of two things: My `.class` file, or the `.xml` file. So here is also my `.xml` file just in case what I have done wrong is there and not in fact in any `.class` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.coppercow.minerman"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

However I've messed around with this xml file quite a lot and so I do not believe it is in here and that My whole problem has to be in some `.class` file somewhere, but I don't even understand how to access those from eclipse from going off of other questions asked here on StackOverflow.

Comment: are you somehow trying to run an Android app as a java app? Android/Dalvik uses dex files not class files.

Comment: OK that makes sense, then i have seen the dex file. Is there anything that i need to do to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it.Mark all checkboxes and Click on Apply and clean the project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it next time I'm at my computer and if it works I'll mark your answer

Comment: That worked if i removed all the Google Play stuff, however it didn't work if i want to keep it. Any ideas on that?