# How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library

Tags: android, gradle, android-multidex

I want to use the new Multidex support library to break the method limit for one of my apps.

With Android Lollipop Google introduced a multidex support library that makes it easy to multidex.

What steps are needed to use this library and to build my app with multidex support?

Comment: **multidex support third party library to your application**

Answer (score 362, accepted):

**Edit:**

Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher uses ART which supports multidexing. Therefore, if your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher, the multidex support library is not needed.

---

Modify your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

         defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
             targetSdkVersion 22

             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

If you are running unit tests, you will want to include this in your `Application` class:

```
public class YouApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```

Or just make your `application` class extend `MultiDexApplication`

```
public class Application extends MultiDexApplication {

}
```

For more info, this [is a good guide.](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

Comment: If you are using the new builds tools yet this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: So, what if I was using the same method described below here from Janusz and all was working fine, and then I updated to android studio 1.0 (and so gradle 1.0) and I'm not able to get it working in any way. Nor this one described by you, that looks like the "official one" for google too.. I still get "failed to run command --multi-dex". Anyone have the same problem?

Comment: @jem88 You updated your gradle to 1.0?? You should be on 2.2.+ (Take a look in your `gradle-wrapper.properties`) The key points: **1** your buildToolsVersion needs to be 21.1.1 or higher. 
**2** add `multiDexEnabled true` to your defaultConfig of your build.gradle (notice there is not a `=`)
**3** add the `'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'`

Comment: @Binghammer Sorry for the mistake, I mean gradle 2.2.1. I've that, I'm using build tools 21.1.1, I've multiDexEnabled true in default config and I've multidex:1.0.0. And all the other things are exactly in the same way I had before the update, when it was working fine. I'm on this from couple of hours now, can't figure this out!

Comment: How about if we don't use application class? Is adding `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` to `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` sufficient?

Comment: Do you not need to add it to the release section as well?

Comment: @Zapanologica   If it is in your 'defaultConfig' you should be good.

Comment: This is how it fixed the Multi-Dex crash on my app, thanks a lot, please refer the link http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' is not needed in 23

Comment: perfect answer!. its worked for me after including multidex enabled true, compile multidex dependancy and add install multidex code in my Application class. its solved my big issue. Thanks @Chad Bingham

Comment: @NaveedAhmad, according to the google developer docs: `..if your minSdkVersion is set to 20 or lower you must use...` `'compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`.

Comment: based on documentation, compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' is required  if your minSdkVersion is set to 20. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: It seems that multidex library is in the maven repository. So check if it's also added in the build.gradle config. Like:
repositories {
...
    mavenCentral()
...
}
and 
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
...
}

It's helped me

Comment: Multydex has new version 1.0.3

Comment: For APIs < 21 you might need to extend `MultiDexApplication` instead of `Application` as well.

Comment: @ratsimihah There is no requirement to extend that class. It is just a helper.

Comment: To be clear, for minSdkVersion 21+, not only the multidex support library but also any configuration of multidex such as "multiDexEnabled true" is unnecessary.

Answer (score 47):

The following steps are needed to start multi dexing:

Add android-support-multidex.jar to your project. The jar can be found in your Android SDK folder /sdk/extras/android/support/multidex/library/libs

Now you either let your apps application class extend MultiDexApplication

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication
```

or you override attachBaseContext like this:

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
 super.attachBaseContext(base);
 MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

I used the override approach because that does not mess with the class hierarchy of your application class.

Now your app is ready to use multi dex. The next step is to convince gradle to build a multi dexed apk. The build tools team is working on making this easier, but for the moment you need to add the following to the android part of your apps build.gradle

```
   dexOptions {
      preDexLibraries = false
   }
```

And the following to the general part of your apps build.gradle

```
afterEvaluate {
   tasks.matching {
      it.name.startsWith('dex')
   }.each { dx ->
      if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
         dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
      } else {
         dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
      }
   }
}
```

More info can be found on [Alex Lipovs blog](http://blog.osom.info/2014/10/multi-dex-to-rescue-from-infamous-65536.html).

Comment: how can I use this without gradle?

Comment: @Janusz is it possible to use multidex option without gradle?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without gradle.

Comment: What is the Eclipse Ant fix, not gradle?

Comment: My project dont create gradle file, i created one and followed your steps, but it is not working for me

Comment: So glad we went to gradle, using ant this would have been a nightmare.

Comment: I am also trying to build my project with moulted support,but while running the application it is crashing saying ClassNotFound Exception for my application class.Also only classes.ex file is created even though I specified splitdexfile.Please help

Comment: I had everything else, but this is what fixed it for me on KitKat devices: dexOptions {
      preDexLibraries = false
   }

Answer (score 24):

Here is an up-to-date approach as of October 2020, with Android X. This comes from Android's documentation, "[Enable multidex for apps with over 64K methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-pre-l)."

### For `minSdk` >= 21

You do not need to do anything. All of these devices use the Android RunTime (ART) VM, which supports multidex natively.

### For `minSdk` < 21

In your *module*-level `build.gradle`, ensure that the following configurations are populated:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

You need to install explicit multidex support. The documentation includes [three methods to do so](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle), and you have to pick *one*.

For example, in your `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, you can declare `MultiDexApplication` as the `application:name`:

```xml
<manifest package="com.your.package"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: For minSdk >= 21 not need multidex - this is true, thanks!

Answer (score 20):

SIMPLY, in order to enable multidex, you need to ...

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

also you must change your manifest file. In your manifest add the MultiDexApplication class from the multidex support library to the application element like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
   <application
       ...
       android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
       ...
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: This will not enable multi dexing. You are still missing the application class.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, This worked for my case.  Here is the link I got reference from https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Yeah, your right. It looks like you don't need to have it in your application class unless you are running tests.

Comment: I don't get this.. My application manifest has already a name tag.  I don't think i will replace it with `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication`

Please guide me..

Comment: @mboy : In that case you have to override attachBaseContext(Context base) in your application class. See Janusz's answer.

Comment: @akshay7692 I have only one activity class(MainActivity) and others are fragments called by pressing some button from the MainActivity.. I'm not sure what is application class is.. Application class is the same as my MainActivty class? Pls correct me if im wrong..

Comment: @mboy : No, MainActivity and application class are different. Know more about application class here : http://rominirani.com/android-application-class/

Comment: I understand now..  Thank you so much!

Comment: I think putting `package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">` is possibly misleading b/c it gives the impression that myapplication class should be included in the package name. It should just be the package root up to but not including the class.

Comment: android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" ... this part saves my life

Answer (score 9):

In your **build.gradle** add this dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

again in your **build.gradle** file add this line to **defaultConfig** block:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Instead of extending your application class from **Application** extend it from **MultiDexApplication** ; like :

```
public class AppConfig extends MultiDexApplication {
```

now you're good to go! And in case you need it, all `MultiDexApplication` does is

```
public class MultiDexApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

build.gradle

```
multiDexEnabled true
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:** Change build.grade

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

**Step 2:** Setting on the Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Change grade.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

It will work!. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting "Cannot find symbol for MultiDex". Anyone faced this problem before?

Answer (score 2):

First you should try with Proguard (This clean all code unused)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So no `MultiDexApplication` and `androidx:multidex` is needed? Why other answers provide two more steps?

Answer (score 1):

Add to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

OR

```
MultiDex.install(this);
```

in your custom Application's attachBaseContext method

or your custom Application extend MultiDexApplication

add multiDexEnabled = true in your build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: @Harsha its not recommended to use this but try to add largeHeap
to your manifest file
    <application
        android:largeHeap="true"></application>

Comment: android:largeHeap="true"
        android:allowBackup="true" am added both

Comment: add this to the gradle file
>>>>>>>>>
     dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }

Answer (score 1):

With androidx, the classic support libraries no longer work.

Simple solution is to use following code

In your `build.gradle` file

```
android{
  ...
  ...
  defaultConfig {
     ...
     ...
     multiDexEnabled true
  }
  ...
}

dependencies {
  ...
  ...
  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

And in your manifest just add name attribute to the application tag

```
<manifest ...>
    <application
        android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
     ...
     ...>
         ...
         ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If your application is targeting API 21 or above multidex is enables by default.

Now if you want to get rid of many of the issues you face trying to support multidex - first try using code shrinking by setting `minifyEnabled true`.

Answer (score 1):

If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, multidex is enabled by default and you do not need the multidex library:

**Modify the module-level build.gradle file to enable multidex and add the multidex library as a dependency, as shown here:**

```
  android {
        defaultConfig {
            ...
            minSdk = 15 
            targetSdk = 28
            multiDexEnabled = true
        }
        ...
    }

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")
}
```

**If you do override the Application class, change it to extend MultiDexApplication (if possible) as follows:**

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

**Or if you do override the Application class but it's not possible to change the base class, then you can instead override the attachBaseContext() method and callMultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex:**

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

for more info check out [this blog](https://dsatechblog.com/uncategorized/app-requires-multidex-support-flutter/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable multi-dex in your project then just go to gradle.builder

and add this in your dependencie

```
 dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'}
```

then you have to add

```
 defaultConfig {
...
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 21
...

// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true}
```

Then open a class and extand it to Application
If your app uses extends the Application class, you can override the oncrete() method and call

```
   MultiDex.install(this)
```

to enable multidex.

and finally add into your manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
   ...
     android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
   ...
   </application>
 </manifest>
```

Comment: What is `gradle.builder`?

Comment: your gradle file which is located in your android studio project

Answer (score 0):

All answers above are awesome

Also add this otherwise your app will crash like mine without any reason

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score -2):

just adding this snipped in the build.gradle also works fine

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 22
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         targetSdkVersion 22

         **// Enabling multidex support.
         **multiDexEnabled true****
     }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Multi_Dex.java

```
public class Multi_Dex extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```