# Multidex application in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-multidex

I've developed an android application in Eclipse which uses lot of library JAR files so i got exception of

```
Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

So i thought to implement multidex. I searched many blogs but nothing helps me in the eclipse framework. So i installed the Gradle plugin for eclipse to achive the multidex which was mentioned in many posts (As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284064/5053350), and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27967363/5053350)). Both telling the same method to add

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

but its not working

I asked my application class to override

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

and in the gradle file which is builded i edited as

```
    android{
            defaultConfig {
                 minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
                 targetSdkVersion 22

                 // Enabling multidex support.
                 multiDexEnabled true
             }
     }
```

But it doesn't helped me. Can anyone help me to find how to multidex my application with eclipse or correct way to multidex with the gradle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling MultiDex Support in Android to achieve 65K+ methods in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27967191/enabling-multidex-support-in-android-to-achieve-65k-methods-in-eclipse)

Comment: I've already posted one link which also says the same method to add 
    multiDexEnabled true but it doen't do the multidexing and still i get the error of 65K methods in eclipse

Comment: having the same issue in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

add this to your gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    ... 
}
```

If that doesn't work, I'm lost as to how to help you because that is the only thing missing that I can see from other answers here on SO.

Comment: I've used this in the gradle file but it doesn't helps me

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 3 things to enable MultiDex:

1) Add following dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

2) Enable multidex in your build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

3) Finally, if you are using a custom Application class, it should extend MultiDexApplication:

```
public class MuyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

}
```

or if you are not using a custom Application class, do the following in your manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Hi, I added the depenencies in gradle file and enabled multidex then extended the application class as MultiDexApplication but still i'm getting the error

Comment: Error :
Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Comment: Have got solution  @S A R