# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 in eclipse while adding google play service lib

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am facing this problem while adding the google play service lib.I have gone through many links. From that, i found that it might be caused by multidex.But i am unable to implement multidex support in eclipse and i need to develop this project only in eclipse.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i didn't add play service in to my project, how to check if already exist or not

Comment: rightClick to project

Comment: go in properties -> android ->if play service is added then will show there

Comment: Otherwise so in libs folder.Both place u can find then delete from one

Comment: no one showing previously, now showing only one that what i add.

Comment: Post your error from console

Comment: [2016-07-27 15:37:58 - Custominspection] Dx 
PARSE ERROR:
[2016-07-27 15:37:58 - Custominspection] Dx unsupported class file version 52.0
...while parsing android/UnusedStub.class
[2016-07-27 15:37:58 - Custominspection] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2016-07-27 15:37:58 - Custominspection] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Comment: You may have two jar file containing same class

Comment: I am using ksoap and dynamicPDF jar with this,

Comment: how to avoid that if it like this?

Comment: Delete class from any which not effects other code

Comment: there is no two class like in same name

Comment: You can try this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883178/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-exporting-apk]

Comment: same problem, not fixed

Comment: "I am unable to implement multidex support in eclipse and i need to develop this project only in eclipse."

 The root of your problem is caused by multidex not being supported in eclipse. I read this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27967191/enabling-multidex-support-in-android-to-achieve-65k-methods-in-eclipse) and it says that this is supported by Gradle/Maven build tools which is integrated in Android Studio. On the other hand, Eclipse uses Ant. So either you move to Android Studio or find a way to make Gradle work in Eclipse for you.