# Facebook Android SDK pushes the app to have more than 64k method in single dex

Tags: android, facebook

Too many methods in it and can not afford to remove other dependencies. Is there a specific Facebook SDK for Facebook Login? What else can I do to use Facebook in my android app?

Comment: Are you using ProGuard in your build process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of API 21 an option for MultiDex is available when building applications with gradle. This will allow you to have more than 64k methods.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library) question as well as the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) for using multi dex.