# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError urban airship after multidex

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, urbanairship.com, android-multidex

I am getting the following error when running my app on a kitkat samsung tablet and a kitkat samsung phone but not on 5.1 nexus 5

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.urbanairship.R$string
        at com.urbanairship.push.NotificationActionButtonGroupFactory.createUrbanAirshipGroups(NotificationActionButtonGroupFactory.java:40)
        at com.urbanairship.push.PushManager.<init>(PushManager.java:224)
        at com.urbanairship.push.PushManager.<init>(PushManager.java:212)
        at com.urbanairship.UAirship.<init>(UAirship.java:109)
        at com.urbanairship.UAirship.executeTakeOff(UAirship.java:323)
        at com.urbanairship.UAirship.access$000(UAirship.java:55)
        at com.urbanairship.UAirship$2.run(UAirship.java:280)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

before using multidex the application was running fine but after adding a big library and having to use multidex I get this error

Comment: How you added multidex? Are you 100% sure that you did it properly?

Comment: I will look into that thanks. where can I find the latest proper way?

Comment: never mind it is solved now! using the instructions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library

Comment: solved now! using the instructions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library