# Android Aws Library - UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, amazon-s3

when i try to use  aws-android-sdk-s3 library i recive this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxl\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --output xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
2
Output:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index 65727 into a non-jumbo instruction!
at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.jumboCheck(InstructionTransformer.java:109)
at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.access$800(InstructionTransformer.java:26)
at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer$StringVisitor.visit(InstructionTransformer.java:72)
at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.callVisit(CodeReader.java:114)
at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.visitAll(CodeReader.java:89)
at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.transform(InstructionTransformer.java:49)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformCode(DexMerger.java:842)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformMethods(DexMerger.java:813)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassData(DexMerger.java:785)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassDef(DexMerger.java:682)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:542)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

this is my gradle

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':extendedCalendarView')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0'
compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.3'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.3'
```

it work all fine till i add the last line and i dont know what can be..searching here on stackoverflow i saw there can be a duplicate declaration of the library support-v4 but i dotn see any :( what can be? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library) . here you can find  the best answer for your question.by default android studio support multidex for exceeds 65k+ methods.jsut simply follow the lines