# Dex method index overflow

Tags: java, android, gradle

it's getting hard to get `gradlew` build the project. This is what I get when I type `./gradlew build`:

```
Not converting this method
Unexpected error while editing code:
  Class       = [Lnet/danlew/android/joda/DateUtils;]
  Method      = [toMillis JL]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Dex method index overflow [67472])
:app:dexguardDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexguardDebug'.
> Dex method index overflow [67472]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3 mins 4.795 secs
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: try this  dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)

Comment: What's the conclusion? Is it the same problem? (method count limit reached, solution - MultiDex)